# python pandas aggregate transaction data into timeframes by customer

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe with transactional data, e.g.

```
                       date            billing.email            DateTime      first_orderdate  first_order  total
date_created                                                                                                      
2020-10-13T01:53:03  2020-10  abc@hotmail.de 2020-10-13 01:53:03  2020-08-23T07:08:02            0  55.24
2020-09-29T01:52:46  2020-09  abc@hotmail.de 2020-09-29 01:52:46  2020-08-23T07:08:02            0  55.24
2020-09-20T07:23:03  2020-09  abc@hotmail.de 2020-09-20 07:23:03  2020-08-23T07:08:02            0  55.24
2020-09-15T01:38:03  2020-09  abc@hotmail.de 2020-09-15 01:38:03  2020-08-23T07:08:02            0  55.24
2020-09-01T01:23:03  2020-09  abc@hotmail.de 2020-09-01 01:23:03  2020-08-23T07:08:02            0  55.24
2020-08-23T07:08:02  2020-08  abc@hotmail.de 2020-08-23 07:08:02  2020-08-23T07:08:02            1  55.24
```

right now, it is only one customer (based on the email), and a little timeframe for developing.

### i want to create an overview of the customer value by a defined timeframe and per customer

```
billing.email   first_orderdate rev_after_2M    rev_after6M     rev_after12M
abc@hotmail.de  2020-08             331,40          331,40          331,40
```

I would now loop over every single customer and calculate that individually, but there must be an easy pandas way ... right?
would be very time consuming with the loop.

thanks for any hint
E.

Comment: Which date column should the "timeframe" be based on? So for example, `rev_after6M`, is it within 6 months of `date_created`, `DateTime`, `first_orderdate`, etc?

Comment: hi. sorry. it should compare the DateTime with the first_orderdate + n Month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution, utilizing `groupby` per email and using some logic to check if the purchase dates happened within 2, 6, 12 months after first order.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Ensure datetime format on all datetime columns
df[['DateTime','first_orderdate']] = df[['DateTime','first_orderdate']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df['rev_after_2M'] = ((df.DateTime - df.first_orderdate)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M') <= 2) * df.total
df['rev_after_6M'] = ((df.DateTime - df.first_orderdate)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M') <= 6) * df.total
df['rev_after_12M'] = ((df.DateTime - df.first_orderdate)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M') <= 12) * df.total

df.groupby(
    ['billing.email', df.first_orderdate.dt.date])[['rev_after_2M', 'rev_after_6M', 'rev_after_12M']]\
  .sum().reset_index()
```

The trick here is to create an indicator column first, saying "does this datetime occur within 2 months (as defined by `numpy` of `first_orderdate`?" If so, this returns `True` and we multiply it by the value of that row (`total`). `True`* `value` = `value` and `False` * `value` = 0, so you end up with these 3 columns representing only the order value if it happened within 2, 6, 12 months.

The final step is to just group by customer email and first order date (as you have in your example), and then summing the revenue per every period. The resulting dataframe (I added another email to illustrate) would be like this:

```
    billing.email     first_orderdate   rev_after_2M    rev_after_6M rev_after_12M
0   abc@hotmail.de    2020-08-23        331.44          331.44       331.44
1   banana@hotmail.de 2020-08-23        55.24           55.24        55.24
```